# Lambda Authorizer not respecting Resource

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I'm generating the following policy which gets cached:

```
{
    'principalId': 'test_user_user_ea8a2822-0b00-4a9c-ad79-27af44700801@123.com',
    'policyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Action': 'execute-api:*',
            'Effect': 'Deny',
            'Resource': 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:12345:hahd712723/active/GET/v1/AccountA'
        }]
    }
}
```

I then make a request to `arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:12345:hahd712723/active/GET/v1/AccountB'`

which should generate:

```
{
    'principalId': 'test_user_user_ea8a2822-0b00-4a9c-ad79-27af44700801@123.com',
    'policyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Action': 'execute-api:*',
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Resource': 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:12345:hahd712723/active/GET/v1/AccountB'
        }]
    }
}
```

but instead of a new cache set, I get the deny policy incorrectly.

**Seems like the principal Id is the only thing looked at and resource is not respected.**

Answer (score 2):

The policy is cached based on the header you select/API key, not based on the header and resource. 
The policy should be constructed for all resources, not just the resource being requested.